# Alert Dialogbox not show every 5 min in Android

Tags: android

My main activity uses AlarmManager to alarm-repeat intent every 5 minutes to call a dialog activity. It's normally working.

Sometimes the intent is called but the dialog does not appear to the user; it hangs the touch screen and menu button. If I press the back button to release, it hangs. I am able to see dialogs in recent applications. How can I show the dialog without pressing the back button and hanging the touch screen/menu button?

MainActivity.java:

```
scheduler = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AlertDialogShow.class );
scheduledIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

AlertDialogShow.java:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogShow.this);//.create();
builder.setCancelable(false);
// Setting Dialog Title
builder.setTitle("Light Brightness");
TextView myMsg = new TextView(this);
myMsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
myMsg.setTextSize(25);
if(Math.round(lux)>=p)
    if(lux<=10243)
        myMsg.setText(Math.round(lux)+" "+"lux."+'\n'+'\n'+"Brightness is High.");
    else
        myMsg.setText(10243+" "+"lux."+'\n'+'\n'+"Brightness is High.");     
else
    // Setting Dialog Message
    myMsg.setText(Math.round(lux)+" "+"lux.");
builder.setView(myMsg);
/* .setButton method is deprecated.so update .setNegativeButton using AlertDialog.Builder*/
// Setting OK Button
builder.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        alertDialog.cancel();
        AlertDialogShow.getInstance().finish();
    }
});

alertDialog= builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Post your code that you have tried.

Comment: can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
alertDialog.cancel();
AlertDialogShow.getInstance().finish();
```

use [`alertDialog.dismiss()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss%28%29) to remove the alertDialog form the current activity.